# Screen is rotating even if I block the landscape rotation

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to block the landscape orientation for some `UIViewController`. I read a lot of different thing to manage it, but I didn't find a solution working well. Every time, the orientation isn't blocked even if it should be.

I have the following code to block the landscape orientation in the `UIViewController` which doesn't have the landscape rotation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Even with that, the view is rotating in landscape.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You need to use custom navigation controller in which you can block the orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`? Or `TabBarController`? In that case, the `UIViewController` just passes that call to the `UINavigationController` and you will have to subclass `UINavigationController` and implement these methods there and check which of the view controllers in the navigation controller's stack is the one that wants to rotate and only allow the rotation for the one that you want.

This is how I did it in a project:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([self.visibleViewController class] == [MyViewController class]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

You can as well try to ask the UIViewController in question from the navigation controller, but this didn't work for me well for some reason.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

You use the same approach for the rest of the methods as well.

Comment: As you said, my ViewController is inside a custom NavigationController. I try your suggestion, but it rotates anyway.

Comment: Maybe try adding shouldAutorotate { return NO} to the other view controllers? But I don't thinks this should be necessary.

Comment: Didn't work too. It looks like it just care about the orientation available, and don't use this methods (even if they are called, just check it out)

Comment: You were right, as you said, I needed a custom navigationController. My problem was due to my lateral menu.